# json parse error Unexpected token o

Tags: javascript, json

I use the following code and I got error,I want to get it **as array of objects** so what I miss here?

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z4oxsa1b/1/

```
 var json = {
  "prov": [
    {
      "save": {
        "pa": "sa",
        "func": "sa"

      },
      "delete": {
        "pa": "sof",
        "func": "delete"

      }
    }
  ]
}

 console.log("Test2");
 var jsonParse = JSON.parse(json);
```

Comment: That sample is valid JavaScript. So it doesn't need to be parsed.

Comment: @icke, You have a point, but JavaScripts parser are forgiving gods. That won't throw an error.

Comment: @icke - do you mean like this https://jsfiddle.net/z4oxsa1b/2/ , the error is still exist

Comment: No like this: https://jsfiddle.net/z4oxsa1b/3/

Comment: @AlBundy - you still have a javascript OBJECT, which is not a JSON string, so it wont parse

Comment: What I know is The JSON.parse() method parses a string as JSON not an object

Comment: @AlBundy, please read into [`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) and [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). There are a bunch of good explanations out there. The links are all to MDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `json` is already a valid javascript object.  You should only use `JSON.parse()` on a string to **parse** it into an object.  For instance

```
var obj1 = {a: 1};
var obj2 = JSON.parse('{"a": 1}');
obj1 == obj2 // true
```

Comment: the variable json is NOT json, it's a javascript object, json is a string - in your answer, the only JSON is `'{"a": 1}'`

Comment: Sorry, misuse of the word JSON there :)  Fixed now

Answer (score -3):

```
var json = {
  "prov": [
    {
      "save": {
        "pa": "sa",
        "func": "sa"

      },
      "delete": {
        "pa": "sof",
        "func": "delete"

      }
    }
  ]
}
alert(json);
alert(JSON.stringify(json));

 console.log("Test2");
 var jsonParse = JSON.parse(json);
```

Your josn var is a valid JSON object. As you can see using alert. You can directly use it.
Only if in any case you have had a String in valid format of JSON, you would have been needed to parse it to JSON object.

https://jsfiddle.net/z4oxsa1b/6/